# Alternative to Google translate API

Tags: jquery, google-translate

I am using the Google translate API, but it seems to destroy the css of the webpage.
For example, it gets rid of background images.
Has anyone an alternative idea? I tried looking for a JQuery solution that translates the text inline, without reloading the page, but could not find anything that works sufficiently.

Thx!

Comment: Destroy the CSS? Well, why wouldn't you like to just *solve* that instead of asking an open question (which is offtopic anyway).

Comment: well after the translation some background images are missing, how am I suppose to fix that? why is it off topic?

Comment: I have no experience with this but I know there is also a service from yahoo. maybe this helps: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/64937-babelizer-api-for-simple-access-to-babelfishaltavi/

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are sending the text of what you want translated, and then replacing the text using something like jQuery.  The problem with this is that this "washes out" your embedded html.
Try sending the html instead, and Google will include it in the translated text, something like $().html() rather than $().text().

Showing us some code would really help.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://www.superawesomejquery.com/plugins/2_jquery-google-translate-plugin/